# Detect video scene change using openCV java

Tags: java, opencv, colors, video-processing

I'm trying to build a java video browser where the "video" is a list of images. I need to detect scene changes where the video cuts to the next scene. I know the boundaries of these "scenes" would have completely different images, where the picture for the new scene and the previous image will have a large drop in the correlation of colors and pixel distribution compared to the images in the same scene.

So far I found that the openCV lib would have a lot of useful functions for this purpose. My initial research tells me to maybe use the compareHist function to compare the color histograms, and if the correlation has a large drop, it indicates a scene change.

However, some literature say that it's challenging to find the right threshold for this method. Is there a simple method that could serve this purpose and is not too complicated to code? I'm not looking for something complicated like motion vector detection, as I don't have the time to implement that. Any pseudocode snippet to demonstrate the idea would be awesome.

Comment: You may take a look at [PySceneDetect](https://pyscenedetect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) from "[scene change detection in video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730081/704244)"